# How to match city names split by space?

Tags: python, string

Trying to figure out given two different types of strings, how to make a determination whether or not a city name is actually a split word? Since working in python, I Split the string and save s[0] for street num, s[-1] for zip code and so on but how to figure out whether the city name may be a split word such as New York or San Jose!?

E.g. : 123 Main Street St. Louisville OH 43071  [City name is single word]

E. g : 45 Holy Grail Al. Niagara Town ZP 32908 [City name 'Niagara Town' is two words]

Forgive the noob question.

Thank you,

Comment: How do you get the addresses in the first place. If it is user input then you can have them enter address line 1 then town etc in different fields instead of in one go and save it as string with commas. Like 123 Main St, London, EC1 0HB. Now you can split by commas. And the town name will be one string no matter how many words.

Comment: Don't apologize for a noob question. Everyone is noob here! Don't worry. Try to explain (as noyanc mentioned) from where you get the string.

Comment: Maybe also start by seeing if there is a certain format in your address strings, else unless by doing a lookup there will not be any safe methods to guarantee identifying 2 part cities.

Comment: Addresses are stored in a list and each entry in a list is stored as a single string. There are only single white space characters in between. For instance it would read as 

'123 Main Street St. Louisville OH 43071'
    
OR 

'45 Holy Grail Al. Niagara Town ZP 32908'


So a little stumped as to how to put regular expression for it!

Answer (score 0):

I making two assumptions here:
1) That the number code before the town name is always numeric
2) That there is no town name with a number name

```
index =   list(filter(lambda x: x[1].isnumeric(),enumerate(x.split())))[-1][0]

" ".join(x.split()[index+1:])
```

So what is happening: We try to identify the last part of the split that is purely numeric, and then get the index of that element.  Then we join all elements after that numeric element.